# Mikrotik, block internet for specific ip but allow traffic for dmz or private network

Tags: dmz, mikrotik

I have Mikrotik RBcAP2n with one lan i one wlan. Wlan WiFi is for clients and Lan is for ADSL. Between MKRB and ADSL I have one server on the same network as MKRB and ADSL. Server have apache web site and server acts as my DMZ.

--|internet|--|ADSL|--172.16.0.0--|MKRB|--192.168.0.0-

```
                       |--|SERVER|
```

IPs for network between ADSL,Server and MKRB is 172.16.0.x

IP for ADSL is 172.16.0.1

IP for MKRB is 172.16.0.2

IP for Server is 172.16.0.254

IPs for network on wlan interface on MKRB is for clients 192.168.0.x

Now, if I want to block internet for specific IPs-Clients on WiFi side of MKRB but allow, for the same clients, traffic to DMZ, how can I achieve this?

For instance, if client have ip 192.168.0.10, MKRB wlan have ip 192.168.0.1.

How to block internet for client 192.168.0.10 but allow him to access to 172.16.0.254?

or

How to block all Public IPs for client 192.168.0.10 but allow him to access to network 172.16.0.0?

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised that nobody has answered you on this question. Look this

```
/ip firewall filter

add chain=forward src-address=192.168.0.10/32 dst-address=!172.16.0.0/24 action=drop
```

That is it for now.
See you another time.